# Movement within a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

My class went over magnetism and electricity, and my professor repeatedly mentioned how the field moves from north to south, and he would say "they" and "it." I wasn't sure if he meant that the field itself was moving, or particles within the field were moving.

If my professor was referring to the field, then what does he mean? I'm confused as to how the field itself can move from north to south. Shouldn't the field be the general region in which there are magnetic forces, and therefore stationary? Or am I misunderstanding something?

I wasn't sure how to phrase this question, so sorry if the title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the way he was describing it is confusing you. First off, let's just clarify the assumption that we are dealing with the magnetic field from a fixed source (ie a magnet). Then:

- As you correctly stated, the magnetic field is stationary and is just a visual representation of how the magnetic field looks in space.
- The field doesn't "move" from north to south but it does point from north to south along the field lines. So a field line points away from the north side and towards the south side.
- Remember that (stationary) charges do not move in a magnetic field.
- The magnetic field applied a force on moving charges that is perpendicular to both the velocity and the magnetic field direction. You can determine the direction from the rh rule and noting that: $F = qv\times B$.

Let me know if this is not clear to you. I hope this clarifies that he probably mean point rather than move as well as some of the other subtleties around magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is probably brought about by history and the use of the English language.

Magnetic field lines (lines of force) are used as a visual aid and were very important in the development of what we now call *Electromagnetism*.
These lines have a number of properties one of which is that they start at a north pole and finish at a south pole.
Here the use of *start* and *finish* might give the impression of movement and this idea of movement may be reinforced by the concept of a magnetic flux linked with an area given that the word *flux* can mean *the rate of flow of . . .*.

A direction arrow on a magnetic field line might also reinforce this idea of movement whereas the arrow actually shows the direction of the force on a (isolated) north pole or the direction in which a compass needle points.

Magnetic field lines are used to help when magnetism is taught but should not be taken too literally.
So your professor (like Faraday) is trying to give you a better understanding of the concept of a magnetic field assigning some properties to the magnetic field which you can visualise.
A magnetic field does not move rather it is moving charges which feel the effect of the magnetic field but for you to be able to predict the direction of the force on a moving charge the magnetic field is given a direction.
The same is true of an electric field except that there is always a force on a charge irrespective of whether it is moving or not.